# Network activity for certain windows service

Tags: windows, service, network-monitoring, network-analysis

What tool you suggest for logging network activity(traffic) for certain windows service?
It's windows service written in C#. Service is connecting to Mysql server in a given time intervals.
I would like to log for some period (24h) and analyse how it behaves.

Windows Resource Monitor does the job but i need it logged to file.
Datetime stamp with send and receive values will be enough.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark can log network traffic to a file, but it will not be tied to a specific Windows Service. Though you can filter so that it will record only traffic involved in a specific conversation. So, you could filter for traffic between the server and the MySql server as well as the specific port that conversation is happening on.

Wireshark is available for Windows, Linux and macOS. It is free in all senses of the word.

You can get Wireshark here: http://wireshark.org/

Comment: I know about wireshark. I used it before. I was thinking that is not the best choice for this situation but when you mentioned i was thinking little more, and because this is only process that connecting to mysql i think it will do the job (for wire shark filter type **mysql**). So this will be marked for answer. Thanks Jack.